# How to Create Web Application in Drupal

Tags: nodes

I have a platform independent specification for a web application. I have attached a very small portion of the UML specification posted here. Is it possible to implement the classes as shown by the diagram.

[image]

I am not a Drupal Expert and I am having very difficult time in explaning the feaures I want to the Drupal Expernt.

Is it possible to develop content type with this kind of structure and do the data entry from single Page.

It would be great if someone could show me the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can build that type of data model using fieldable entities in Drupal 7.

For example add base "Member" fields to the user entity and use [entityreference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) for the related reference fields on other entities (similar to a foreign key relationship)

The [addressfield](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module provides a good standard address field and associated data structure to hold that info.

In your model, because it appears a "Member" may have many "Member Contact" records, you could perhaps just create a node type for "Member Contact" and add an entity reference field to the relevant "Member".

More info on [Drupal 7 Entity API](https://drupal.org/node/1261744)

Lastly, if you want to do it completely custom, you can define your own entity types with [`hook_entity_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7)

Comment: In the model one Member(M) have multiple MemberLocation (ML) and MultipleContact(MC) Information. 
MemberLocation is Derived from Address. Fax,Email,Phone from MC. Credit and MemberType has 1 to 1 Relation with the M class.

So I will create content types:
1. M having flds of M, Credit and MType
2. ML having fields of address
3. Fax, Email and Phone having fields of MC

M will have 1 to * relation with MC and ML I should  use entityreference module. 
In data entry, all the data is entered at the same time. Will entityreference work? Does it need MC and ML created before creating the M itself.

Comment: MemberLocation looks like a multiple value address field attached to the user entity. Otherwise, it could be a node type with a user reference field and an addressfield on it. I'll leave you to work out the details, but that's the gist of it.